# Replacement string not working in GNU parallel

Tags: gnu-parallel

I have the script `run_md.py` which produces the file `test.dcd` from the input file named `test.pdb`.
I want to execute the same command on multiple input files (`test*.pdb`) on a remote server using GNU parallel and transfer the result back to the local computer. Therefore, I'm using the following command:

```
parallel --trc {.}.dcd -j 2 -S $SERVER1 './run_md.py {} 1000' ::: test*.pdb
```

The command is running as expected on the server using 2 slots. However, the files are not transferred back and I get the following error:

```
rsync: link_stat "/home/bougui/{.}.dcd" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1655) [Receiver=3.1.1]
```

It looks like the replacement string is not working. How can I make it works?

Below is the output of `parallel --version`:

```
GNU parallel 20130922
Copyright (C) 2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013 Ole Tange and Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
GNU parallel comes with no warranty.

Web site: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel

When using GNU Parallel for a publication please cite:

O. Tange (2011): GNU Parallel - The Command-Line Power Tool, 
;login: The USENIX Magazine, February 2011:42-47.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug reported in that thread has been fixed and this feature works well with the latest version of GNU parallel (20160622). The GNU parallel version 20130922 packaged with Debian 8.5 is buggy for the usage of `{.}` string replacement, as described below:

With more test I found that the output file must be specified with a replacement string in the command run in parallel.

For testing purpose, you can find below a complete example that others can run:

```
echo This is input_file > input_file && parallel --trc {}.out -S $SERVER1 cat {} ">"{}.out ::: input_file
```

The example above works well. When I use the substitution string `{.}` as below:

```
echo This is input_file > input_file.in && parallel --trc {.}.out -S $SERVER1 cat {} ">"{.}.out ::: input_file
```

It works, as well. However, if I didn't specify `{.}.out` in the command run in parallel as below:

```
echo This is input_file > input_file.in && parallel --trc {.}.out -S $SERVER1 cat {} ">"input_file.out ::: input_file
```

... I reproduce the error:

```
rsync: link_stat "/home/bouvier/{.}.out" failed: No such file or   directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1655) [Receiver=3.1.1]
rsync: [Receiver] write error: Broken pipe (32)
```

Therefore the output file must be specified in the command run in parallel.

Comment: Please check if this is also a problem in the newest version of GNU Parallel. It sounds like a fixed bug.

Comment: Yes, it works with the last version (20160622). So the GNU parallel (version 20130922) packaged with Debian 8.5 seems buggy for this feature.

Comment: I added versions informations about the GNU parallel versions in my answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is 100% correct. So something on your system is breaking this. Please try this on another system and if possible follow REPORTING BUGS from `man parallel`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tried the command on a Debian 8.5 with parallel package and on Ubuntu 14.04 with parallel package. SERVER1 is a CentOS release 6.8. I've also tried to change SERVER1 to the Ubuntu 14.04 machine and launching parallel from the Deban machine and I got the same error. I use zsh as shell. I don't manage to figure out what's going on.

Comment: I tested with zsh, it works fine on my machine, too. If you can reproduce the bug as described in REPORTING BUGS maybe we can figure out the error.